# Two cevians divide a triangle into 4 parts. Calculate the area of the 4th part, given the other 3.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles, triangulation

Good day

Here is the question:

[image]

Connecting $AF$ and setting areas $\triangle ADF = x$ and $\triangle AFE = y$:

$\frac {9+x}{12} =\frac y{15}$

$\frac{15+y}{12} =\frac x9$
from the ratios of the sides to the areas.

I get the areas $x = 315$ and $y = 405$, though according to the image it seems impossible.

Am I missing something or is it correct?

Comment: *according to the image it seems impossible* - The image isn't up to scale, in case you haven't noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $[ABC]$ be the area of $\triangle{ABC}$.

Let $[ADF]=x,[AEF]=y$. Then, from
$$AD:DB=[ADF]:[DFB]=[ADC]:[CDB],$$
one has
$$x:9=x+y+15:9+12\tag1$$

Also, from
$$BF:FE=[BFA]:[FEA]=[BFC]:[CFE],$$
one has
$$x+9:y=12:15\tag2$$

Solving $(1)(2)$ gives
$$x=315,y=405.$$

Hence, $$[ADFE]=x+y=315+405=\color{red}{720}.$$

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify it's the areas we are looking for. I see you get the same so I can say I got it right?

Comment: @user253171: I believe we are right. You may think our answer seems too big for the image. But this sometimes happens. The image is just an image. It is not strict.